# Is there a way to count duplicated numbers using reduce and iterating once?

Tags: javascript, node.js, iteration

I asked myself If there was a way to solve the problem of counting duplicated numbers just **iterating once** and also using the `reduce` method.

This is what I got:

```js
const countDuplicate = (numbers) => {
  const occurrencies = {};
  for (var k = 0; k < numbers.length; k++) {
    occurrencies[numbers[k]] = isNaN(occurrencies[numbers[k]])
      ? 1
      : occurrencies[numbers[k]] + 1;
  }
  const counter = Object.values(occurrencies).reduce(
    (total, each) => total + (each > 1 ? 1 : 0),
    0
  );
  return counter;
};

countDuplicate([1,2,3,4]); // returns 0
countDuplicate([1,2,3,4,1,2,2]); // returns 2
```

Comment: `x.length - (new Set(x)).size` <= would tell you how many characters were removed because they were duplicates

Comment: You *are* iterating `numbers` only once. There's nothing wrong with your code. (Well, you could work on the `counter` during that loop, but it would be less readable)

Comment: I am iterating `numbers` once although  I used `occurrencies` as an auxiliar data structure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can definitely be done in one pass - your accumulator can be an object, storing seen numbers quantity in one property and number of seen duplicates in another. So, when the minimum *dup* requirement is met (number is seen exactly twice), you get the dups quantity increased (further occurrences of this number will be simply ignored) :

```js
const src = [1,2,3,4,1,2,2],

      {countDups} = src.reduce((r, n) => {
        r.countN[n] = (r.countN[n]||0)+1
        r.countN[n] == 2 && r.countDups++    
        return r
      }, {countN:{}, countDups: 0})
      
console.log(countDups)
```

Comment: Thank you Yevgen! this is what I expected!