# Reduce callback function to retrieve properties from an array

Tags: javascript, function, callback

Given the following array I am to write a callback function for reduce to return an object that has two keys-'JavaScript' & 'python'. The keys should be equal to the number of developers that have 'JavaScript' or 'python' as their language. The final console log should read JavaScript: 4, Python:3.

```
const developersArray = [
    { name: 'ralph', language: 'javascript' },
    { name: 'gretchen', language: 'javascript' },
    { name: 'alice', language: 'python' },
    { name: 'mohammed', language: 'javascript' },
    { name: 'pat', language: 'python' },
    { name: 'taylor', language: 'python' },
    { name: 'hideo', language: 'javascript' },
];
```

So far this is what i came up with. I am looking back at an old assignment and think i was on the right track but not sure if i am headed the right way:

```
const devLanguageCounts = developersArray.reduce(() => developersArray.language === 'javascript' && 'python' ? ++developersArray : 'javascript', 'python');
```

Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: No, your solution is not even close to correct.

Comment: You're missing the arguments to the callback function (the current accumulator and current element). You're missing the second argument to `reduce` (the initial value of the accumulator). You're not adding a property to the accumulator or incrementing it.

Comment: What is `++developersArray` supposed to mean? `++` is for integers, it makes no sense on an array.

Comment: `developersArray.language === 'javascript' && 'python'` is wrong on several counts.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62722268/is-there-a-way-to-count-duplicated-numbers-using-reduce-and-iterating-once for how to do it with an array of numbers. Adapting it to an array of objects should be simple.

Comment: I think I was trying to iterate over the array but clearly not doing it correctly. I am going to start over and re-learn it. Thank you for the information

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `reduce` dynamically using [Logical_nullish_assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_nullish_assignment) which initial `object` if the language does not exist with 0 or get its previous value, then increment it.

```js
const developers = [
  { name: "ralph", language: "javascript" },
  { name: "gretchen", language: "javascript" },
  { name: "alice", language: "python" },
  { name: "mohammed", language: "javascript" },
  { name: "pat", language: "python" },
  { name: "taylor", language: "python" },
  { name: "hideo", language: "javascript" },
];
const devLanguageCounts = developers.reduce((prev, { language }) => {
  prev[language] ??= 0;
  prev[language]++;
  return prev;
}, {});
console.log(devLanguageCounts);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Simple approach with `forEach` with checking with `hasOwnProperty` if language already exist in `res` increment it elsewhere initial it with 1:

```js
const developers = [
  { name: "ralph", language: "javascript" },
  { name: "gretchen", language: "javascript" },
  { name: "alice", language: "python" },
  { name: "mohammed", language: "javascript" },
  { name: "pat", language: "python" },
  { name: "taylor", language: "python" },
  { name: "hideo", language: "javascript" },
];
   
res = {};
developers.forEach(({ language }) => {
  if (res.hasOwnProperty(language)) {
    res[language] += 1;
  } else {
    res[language] = 1;
  }
});
console.log(res)
```

Comment: You're not using `reduce()`.